# How can i use ManyToManyRawIdWidget outside admin?

Tags: django, widget, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django: using ForeignKeyRawIdWidget outside of admin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271080/django-using-foreignkeyrawidwidget-outside-of-admin-forms)

Im new to django and I would like to know how could i use the ManytoManyRawId widget outside admin.

I've tried different ways but still don't work. Help would be really much appreciated.

Comment: How it "Don't work" ? Show a code snippet, describe what you expect and what you get

Comment: See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271080/django-using-foreignkeyrawidwidget-outside-of-admin-forms-solved