# Django: using ForeignKeyRawIdWidget outside of admin forms

Tags: django, forms, admin, widget

I'm trying to find some documentation of how to use the ForeignKeyRawIdWidget in my own forms. Currently I keep getting the error, "**init**() takes at least 2 non-keyword arguments (1 given)" which tells me nothing.

Any help would be most appreciated. Googling this turns up little but dev conversations and no examples that I can find of how to implement it.

**Update**: This is solved; see solution below.

Comment: Can you show how you try to initialize the widget?

Comment: If you solved this on your own, please post your solution as an answer and accept that. Including the solution in the question is confusing.

Comment: Better? Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of the Django 1.5, this works to reuse the ForeignKeyRawIdWidget in non-admin forms.

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import site

class InvoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        widgets = {
            'customer': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(Invoice._meta.get_field('customer').rel, site),
        }
```

**Update**

Django 2.0 is deprecating `field.rel` in favor of `field.remote_field`. You might want to use this instead (also works on Django 1.11):

```
...
ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(Invoice._meta.get_field('customer').remote_field, site),
...
```

Comment: In Django 2.0 `rel` has been deprecated (`RemovedInDjango20Warning: Usage of field.rel has been deprecated. Use field.remote_field instead.`). You might want to edit the answer to keep it up to date.

Comment: Works perfectly for the new widget `AutocompleteSelect` too

Answer (score 0):

This is from the source code (`django.contrib.admin.widgets`):

```
class ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(forms.TextInput):
    """
    A Widget for displaying ForeignKeys in the "raw_id" interface rather than
    in a <select> box.
    """
    def __init__(self, rel, attrs=None):
        self.rel = rel
        super(ForeignKeyRawIdWidget, self).__init__(attrs)

    #.....
```

From the remaining code, I would guess that `rel` is the foreign key field of your model. At one point, the code checks `self.rel.limit_choices_to`, and this attribute (`limit_choices_to`) can only be set on a `ForgeinKey` field.

Comment: I reviewed this code as well... Not exactly the example or documentation I was hoping for! And it makes it very difficult to troubleshoot when you don't get anything at all.