# Django - How I can populate data in a model from another table/model in the same database?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a form that once is filled out, I'd like for it to cross-check the Employee # with another model's data and if the person exists, then the name would be automatically populated with the matching person once the entry is submitted. Currently I have this, but I'm not sure how to check for the number and then take the name of the person and copy it elsewhere.

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(models.Model):
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    adp_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False) #(max_length=50, help_text="Employee #", blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, help_text="Work Area", related_name="work_area")
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(StationNumber, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Station", related_name="stations", blank=True, )
    time_in = models.DateTimeField(help_text="Time in", null=True, blank=True)
    time_out = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, help_text="Time out", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.adp_number
```

and I have another model in the database which stores current employees with their names and ID #'s, which looks sorta like this.

```
class Salesman(models.Model):
    slsmn_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    adp_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=6)
    ...
```

This is my views too, just in case. I created a function which returns the employee name from the database that has it, but I'm not sure how to use it of if there's another way to approach this.

```
class EnterExitArea(CreateView):
    model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    template_name = "operations/enter_exit_area.html"
    form_class = WarehouseForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        emp_num = form.cleaned_data['adp_number']
        area = form.cleaned_data['work_area']
        station = form.cleaned_data['station_number']

        if 'enter_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)

        elif 'leave_area' in self.request.POST:
            form.save()
            EmployeeWorkAreaLog.objects.filter(adp_number=emp_num, work_area=area, station_number=station).update(time_out=datetime.now())
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)


def get_employee_name(request):
    adp_number = request.POST.get('adp_number')
    employee = Salesman.objects.get(adp_number=adp_number)
    employee_name = employee.slsmn_name
    return employee_name
```

Comment: where do you want to perform this check? in `form_valid()`? What two fields do you want to check?

Comment: @SamCreamer I want it to be as soon as the person tabs out/ clicks out of the field, so that eventually I can display the name of the person right on top before they fill out the rest of the form, once I get to how ajax requests work, and also so that an invalid ID cannot be used to create an entry

Comment: Could you not make the `employee_number` a `ForeignKey` field to `adp_number`? You could then use a `ModelChoiceField` in the form to select the employee number, or use `django-autocomplete-light` to look up employee ids.

Comment: Can `EmployeeWorkAreaLog` contain records for # not present in `Salesman`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin No, only ID#'s stored in salesman already

Comment: So yes, this a FK behaviour, as Lockwood surmised.

Comment: I tried to do this, but now the employee# has become a dropdown with several options that just say "Salesman object ("a number")", instead of a field where a person can type their number and check if it's valid. I have updated the code under EmployeeWorkAreaLog @MikeyLockwood

Comment: @MarianaGomez-Kusnecov You will need to modify to `adp_number` field's widget in the form to change it from a dropdown. I think what you want is a `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget`. Or you could implement `django-autocomplete-light` and do a lookup. Examples are in the links below. Post your code for `WarehouseForm` if you need help with this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271080/django-using-foreignkeyrawidwidget-outside-of-admin-forms 

 https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html