# Django - How to make a ForeignKey dropdown into a textbox?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have a form that has a field which is a ForeignKey since it makes sure that the ID # being entered is one that exists in the database. After making it be a ForeignKey, it changed my field to look like a dropdown in the form as shown below, that contains a bunch of options called "**Salesman object (**'a number'**)**", instead of it being a text box like it was before. The user is supposed to be able to enter their "adp" number and it should only allow numbers in salesman.

[image: Dropdown]

Before I had made this change, I just had the **adp_number** under fields in forms.py, and not as a ForeignKey, which made me not be able to cross check with the Salesman model which contains all the valid **adp_number**'s.

I tried following this [Django: using ForeignKeyRawIdWidget outside of admin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271080/django-using-foreignkeyrawidwidget-outside-of-admin-forms) since I'm not using admin either, but once I made the field into a widget it just stopped showing on my page altogether and I'm not sure what needs to be changed.

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'adp_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('adp_number').remote_field, site),
        }
        fields = ('work_area', 'station_number')
```

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(models.Model):
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    adp_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, help_text="Work Area", related_name="work_area")
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(StationNumber, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Station", related_name="stations", blank=True)
```

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" data-stations-url="{% url 'operations:ajax_load_stations' %}" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <div>
                {{ form.adp_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.adp_number }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.work_area.help_text }}
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.station_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.station_number }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
                <button type="submit" name="leave_area" value="Leave">Leave Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock main %}
```

Comment: It only stopped showing on your page because you removed it from the `fields` tuple.  See also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: what if you give `adp_number` in fields tuple? Does it show now?

Comment: Yes, thank you both!!